# Bootstrap 4 dropdown-menu not working on .net MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I am creating an application in C# .NET MVC. My _Layout.cshtml file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation" wfd-invisible="true">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Dropdown link
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbardrop" wfd-invisible="true">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>
                <li class="nav-item">@Html.ActionLink("Member List", "Index", "Member", null, new { @class = "nav-link" })</li>


            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container body-content mt-4">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/popper")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

My _LoginPartial.cshtml file is

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


            @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" , @class="text-blue"})
            <button class="btn btn-outline-warning " type="submit">Logout</button>

}
}
else
{
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink",@class="text-blue" })</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("| Log in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink", @class = "text-blue ml-1" })</li>
</ul>
}
```

The issue is that the Dropdown menu did not work even though all the other nav-items are working fine. I have tried

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
```

but it does not work either.

All the JS and CSS files exists and linked correctly.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this as it might be useful for others.

The Bootstrap that comes with .NET MVC in Visual Studio is Bootstrap 3. I downloaded a Bootstrap 4 theme from Bootswatch. So now I have Bootstrap 4 CSS and Bootstrap 3 JS. This causes an incompatibility that results in the issue that I described.

Using similar versions fixes the issue.